# What does the ":" mean in gradle android dependency package name?

Tags: android

For example if I depend on the Android Support Library, I add this line in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0"
}
```

My questions are:

1. Where does the "support-core-utils" and version code is defined in
   the support library?
2. What's the benefit of specifying the lib name and version
   code?

Answer (score 3):

The `:` is a separator used in the shortcut definition of an external library.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0"
}
```

stands for

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-core-utils', version: '24.2.0'
}
```

[Here is some documentation.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#sec:external_dependencies_tutorial)

About the Support library, you can read the [support library features list](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html) in order to know which part of the support library to add to your project (instead of adding everything and ending with a huge APK :) )

To my mind, the benefit of specifying the version code, is to allow a developer to only update to the last version of a library, when he is sure that his code is compliant with the last changes in this library.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the “:” mean in gradle android dependency package name?
>   Where does the "support-core-utils" and version code is defined in the support library?

`:` is a separator to enable you to declare a [maven dependency](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) group ID, artifact ID and version in a concise way. All three are required to identify a dependency in a maven repository.

Android SDK manager installs a local maven repository ("Android Support Repository") where the actual versions of the support libraries are found.

> What's the benefit of specifying the lib name and version code?

The build tooling can find your dependencies and successfully build code that depend on such libraries.